# Page broken after Ajax call on leaflet map

Tags: html, jquery, flask, leaflet, package

I'm using a Flask web app to render a page with a leaflet map, my page contains filters with `selectpicker` dropdown options, once I'm sending the Ajax post once, all my page is broken, the filters won't respond I might have packages conflicts. Here is a portion of my HTML code :

## carte.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}

<br/><br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="titre_pages">
        <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="rectangle_rapport"></div></br>
</div>

        <div class="col">
            <label><b>Three :</b></label></br> 
            <select name="ithree" id="ithree" style="width:220px;" class="selectpicker" title=".." data-size="8" style="width: 210px;" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" multiple required></select></br>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label><b>Four :</b></label></br> 
            <select class="selectpicker" name="ifour" id="ifour" title="..." style="width: 210px;" data-size="8" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" multiple required></select></br>

        </div>
    </div>


<div class="container" style="position: relative;height: 350px;">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
</div>


<script>
  $.ajax({
       (...)
        success: function(response) {
            $('#map').html(response);
        },
</script>
```

## layout.html

​ [image]

The leaflet `map.html` that I'm generating creates its own packages inside my `carte.html` page:
[image: Map.html]

And here is the result in my JS console after I rendered my leaflet map once :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
> at HTMLSelectElement. (carto:503)
> at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
> at HTMLSelectElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

```
carto:503 :  $('#three').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: You should ensure that there's enough code to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem; there should be *code* and not *screenshots of code*. Anyhow, chances are that you're forgetting to load [`bootstrap-select`](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select) somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you loaded jquery twice once in layout once in map page loading it twice make it work for first time and then entire functions
will give error on second load first picture line 15 from header tag first time you loaded jquery line 8 from second picture second jquery loading just remove the second one
btw using cdn for bootstrap and jquery and so on will make your response awfully slow

Comment: is there a problem with answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was PHP 7.4, page has broken instead of Error, I changed it back to 7.3 it works and I see the errors again.